# How to migrate SharePoint Workflows using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, content-migration

I am migrating subsites to a different site collection using Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb. However, I am losing all OOTB workflows as well as SPD workflows via this means. The SPD workflows exists and can be seen via SharePoint Designers, but all associations with list/library are lost in the destination.

My ask to all SP experts here - Is there any way we can migrate the workflows via Powershell?